# What does for i in range(1, len(motels)): mean where there are multiple parameters in the range

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am looking at some code but don't understand what passing in multiple parameters means in the range of a for loop in Python

`for i in range(1, len(motels)):`

Comment: 1 is the start index, 0th index will be omitted. and iteration will start from 1st index.

Comment: `range([start_index], end_index, [step])`

Comment: @dawg Actually, its either `range(stop)` or `range(start, stop[, step])`

Comment: @BugHunter The range object is not about indexes but about integers. Your statements, that the "0th index will be omitted" is confusing at its best. There is a "0th index" its value is `1`. What is omitted is the *value* `0` not the *index* `0`.

Comment: @KlausD., Yes, you are right, it is about integers, not index. Integers will be in the range [1, n-1] instead of [0, n-1].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The built-in function `range` takes 1, 2, or 3 parameters.

With only one parameter, it's `range(stop)` and is equivalent to `range(0, stop, 1)`.

With two parameters, it's `range(start, stop)` and is equivalent to `range(start, stop, 1)`.

With three parameters, it generates numbers starting from `start`, with an increment step of `step` (3rd argument) and stops before the number goes greater or equal to `stop`. So `range(1, 11, 3)` will generate 1, 4, 7, 10.

Answer (score 2):

If you have 
for i in range(1, len(motels)):
The variable "i" is going to be some number (in this case) from 1 to whatever is the length of the variable motels.
So if len(motels) = 5, and the code looked like this:

```
for i in range(1, len(motels)):
   print(i)
```

The output would be:
    1
    2
    3
    4

Comment: "from 1 to whatever is the length of the variable motels" - to be more precise, "from 1 to one less than the length of the variable motels," of course.

Answer (score 0):

By default the first parameter in `range` is 0. So for example, `for i in range(5)` is equivalent to `for i in range(0, 5)`.